# IntelliJ IDEA key binding or config to strip file header

Tags: intellij-idea

I can configure IDEA to remove trailing spaces. How can I configure it to remove file headers?

Alternatively, what key binding can I use to remove the file header?

Comment: What type of content do you mean by file headers? Copyright?

Comment: yes. Any comments above package declaration basically